# Path-finding algorithm for a game

Tags: c++, algorithm, path-finding

I have this assigment in university where I'm given the code of a C++ game involving pathfinding. The pathfinding is made using a wave function and the assigment requires me to make a certain change to the way pathfinding works.

The assigment requires the pathfinding to always choose the path farthest away from any object other than clear space. Like shown here:

[image]

And here's the result I've gotten so far:

[image]

Below I've posted the part of the Update function concerning pathfinding as I'm pretty sure that's where I'll have to make a change.

```
for (int y = 0, o = 0; y < LEVEL_HEIGHT; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < LEVEL_WIDTH; x++, o++) {
        int nCost = !bricks[o].type;
        if (nCost) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                int dx = s_directions[j][0], dy = s_directions[j][1];
                if ((y == 0 && dy < 0)
                    || (y == LEVEL_HEIGHT - 1 && dy > 0)
                    || (x == 0 && dx < 0)
                    || (x == LEVEL_WIDTH - 1 && dx > 0)
                    || bricks[o + dy * LEVEL_WIDTH + dx].type)
                {
                    nCost = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        pfWayCost[o] = (float)nCost;
    }
}
```

Also here is the [Wave function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSZOL.jpg) if needed for further clarity on the problem.

I'd be very grateful for any ideas on how to proceed, since I've been struggling with this for quite some time now.

Comment: It would be much easier if you could describe the difference with words rather than pointing to one specific example. (There's a fair chance that you'll solve the problem while describing it.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added a more in-depth description of the assigment.

Comment: Have a look at [Voronoi Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) and then get your path from start to the nearest partition edge, from end to the nearest partition edge and from start to end along partition edges. Through be warned, this might be overkill for a tiled map

Comment: As far as I can see you assign a cost of 1 to moves between spaces and a cost of 2 to impossible moves from a space. You should chosse the cost so that your desired path is the cheapest, so your cost should involve the distance to the nearest obstacle in some way. You use floating-point costs, so you could try something like 1 / d². (That approach will invove some kind of nearest-object search or a suitable precalculation of weights.)

Comment: @M Oehm I'm not sure I quite understood that. For what does the 'd' stand in your equation?

Comment: A question about the requirement: is it just about being as far as possible away from objects on the shortest path or is it about chosing the path where the minimum distance to object is as big as possible (chosing a longer path for more space)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be reduced to a problem known as [minimum-bottle-neck-spanning-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bottleneck_spanning_tree).

For the reduction do the following:

1. calculate the costs for every point/cell in space  as the minimal distance to an object.
2. make a graph were edges correspond to the points in the space and the weights of the edges are the costs calculated in the prior step. The vertices of the graph corresponds to the boundaries between cell.

For one dimensional space with 4 cells with costs 10, 20, 3, 5:

```
|10|20|3|5|
```

the graph would look like:

```
 A--(w=10)--B--(w=20)--C--(w=3)--D--(w=5)--E
```

With nodes A-E corresponding to the boundaries of the cells.

3. run for example the [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) to find the MST. You are looking for the direct way from the entry point (in the example above A) to the exit point (E) in the resulting tree.